# Javascript multi images colour change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following which lets users choose which team they think will win and by how many points

![enter image description here][1]

Based on user selection image-border highlights red for the team user selected.

My problem is, my code only does this for the 1st fixture/match and not the 2nd,3rd,4th etc as you can see in image

Im sure this should be an easy fix, but I just cant seem to get it working...any help would be tremendously appreciated

```
function border() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("t1")[0];
     var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName("t2")[0];
    if (document.getElementById("one").checked) { 

        el.style.borderColor = "red";
        el.style.borderStyle = "solid";
           el2.style.borderColor = "";
        el2.style.borderStyle = "none";
    }

      else if (document.getElementById("two").checked) { 
       el.style.borderColor = "";
        el.style.borderStyle = "none";
        el2.style.borderColor = "red";
        el2.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    }   
}




 <label class="blue"><input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="one" value="'.$row['team1'].'"><span>'.$team1.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="two" value="'.$row['team2'].'"><span>'.$team2.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="three" value="draw"><span>Draw</span></label><br />


echo'<div class="teams">';
        echo'<img src="images/teams/'.$src1.'.png" class="t1"  />'; 
        echo'<img src="images/teams/'.$src2.'.png" class="t2"  />'; 
    echo'</div>';
```

Remember fixtures are generated in a php loop from database depending on how many matches there are in a given round

Comment: Because you are getting only first element`var el = document.getElementsByClassName("t1")[0]`

Comment: @Tushar thanks! lets say I loop it `varx=0("t1")[$x]x++` how would I know when to stop loop since nr matches are never the same...

Comment: @Tushar sure will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all the matching elements and loop over them.

```
function border() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('t1'),
        el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('t2');

    var borderColor1 = '',
        borderStyle1 = 'none',
        borderColor2 = '',
        borderStyle2 = 'none';


    if (document.getElementById('one').checked) {
        borderColor1 = 'red';
        borderStyle1 = 'solid';
    } else if (document.getElementById('two').checked) {
        borderColor2 = 'red';
        borderStyle2 = 'solid';
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].borderColor = borderColor1;
        el[i].borderStyle = borderStyle1;
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < el2.length; j++) {
        el2[j].borderColor = borderColor2;
        el2[j].borderStyle = borderStyle2;
    }
}
```

jQuery Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dkstwrbf/

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee Can you create jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can loop through all matched element instead of processing only first one

```
function border() {
    var oneChecked = $('#one').is(':checked');
    var twoChecked = $('#two').is(':checked');

    $('.t1').each(function(){
       if(oneChecked)
       {
         $(this).siblings('t2').css({'border':'none'});
         $(this).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
       }
       else if(twoChecked)
       {
         $(this).css({'border':'none'});
         $(this).siblings('t2').css({'border':'1px solid red'});
       }
    });   
}
```

Comment: @Bhusan Thank you very much please see updated question, the problem with above code is when I click 1st radio button all other elemnts get selected...